# How to define global wpdb to use inside custom folder?

Tags: php, wordpress

Inside my custom theme folder, I have created a folder named `api`. Inside this folder I have a file named `test.php`.

In this file I need to retrieve some data from my custom tables.

### test.php

```
global $wpdb;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_users ORDER BY name";

$query = $wpdb->prepare($sql);
```

But this is giving me error because, wpdb is null.

Can anybody help me how can I define this $wpdb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering in a directory under themes directory, here is how you include/require the file

```
require_once ('path/to/wordpress/wp-includes/wp-config.php');
require_once( 'path/to/wordpress/wp-includes/wp-db.php' );
require_once("path/to/wordpress/wp-includes/wp-load.php");
```

OR

Go to `wp-config.php` file

and check this line

`define('WP_CACHE', true);` 
If you find then change it to

`define('WP_CACHE', false);`

You may need to alter the path based on your system.

Comment: you can potentially use  `__DIR__` to make a relative path based on current directory the file currently is in. As long as the wordpress path conventions don't change it's a safe bet.

Comment: I have already tried require_once ("./wp-config.php");
require_once ("./wp-includes/wp-db.php");

It gives Warning: require_once(./wp-config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\xampp\htdocs\

Comment: @ArpitJain I am getting Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Object of class wpdb could not be converted to string in

Comment: @nas please check i have updated my answer with one more solution hope that worked in your case.

Comment: Requiring `wp-load.php` is enough. It automatically includes everything required.

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
$pagePath = explode('/wp-content/', dirname(__FILE__));
include_once(str_replace('wp-content/' , '', $pagePath[0] . '/wp-load.php'));
global $wpdb;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_users ORDER BY name";
$query = $wpdb->prepare($sql);
```

and put your test.php at root

Comment: I get Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Object of class wpdb could not be converted to string in